# How to print Log4j java sql logger

Tags: java, log4j, log4jdbc

I want to use log4j for java and sql. i want to print the java and sql logs without using **"logger.debug("log4j logger")"** in my class.

Below are the class and log4j properties used

```
package com.log4j;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
public class LogTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      final  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class);
      PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection   conn = DriverManager.getConnection("XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ");          
       String inserQuery = "insert into table1 (name,id) values (?,?)";
       PreparedStatement prestat = conn.prepareStatement(inserQuery);
       prestat.setString(1, "Test");
       prestat.setString(2, "2");
       prestat.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage() + "");

    }
}

}
```

Below is the log4j properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CA
log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Please advise.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Saying you want to use log4j without using logger.debug() is like saying you want to use a gun without using any bullets.  I suppose there are many other methods to log with, logger.trace() and logger.info() but you haven't made your reason for not using debug clear.  Having System.out.println() in here as well is like adding a bow and arrow.  Please explain WHY you don't want to use logger.debug()

Comment: SQL statements have to print like below without using logger.debug() and by enabling it in the log4j properties.                                 log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG

Comment: Below is the sql logs ,DEBUG [main] - {conn-100003} Connection
DEBUG [main] - {conn-100003} Preparing Statement:    INSERT INTO USERINFO (ID,NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,STATUS)    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);
DEBUG [main] - {pstm-100004} Executing Statement:    INSERT INTO USERINFO (ID,NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,STATUS)    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its like u created a variable which is never used then why create it, it would be better if you use

```
logger.error("Exception: " + ex.getMessage() + "");
```

instead of

```
System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage() + "");
```

Comment: SQL statements have to print like below without using logger.debug() and by enabling it in the log4j properties.                                 log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG

Comment: Below is the sql logs ,DEBUG [main] - {conn-100003} Connection
DEBUG [main] - {conn-100003} Preparing Statement:    INSERT INTO USERINFO (ID,NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,STATUS)    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);
DEBUG [main] - {pstm-100004} Executing Statement:    INSERT INTO USERINFO (ID,NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,STATUS)    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);

Comment: jdbc library will print this log any how, you dont have to do anything for this.

Answer (score 1):

If java.sql has a logger interface it will probably be java.util.logging rather than LOG4J or SLF4J. I've looked at a few of the java.sql.* classes and it looks as if they have no logging at all. Your scheme would have worked had any of these classes used 4J logging but they don't so you'll just have to put the logging in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the **SQL** sent to the database, you might want to use [**log4jdbc-log4j2**](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-log4j2/). This acts as a proxy:

[image: Proxy]

If you use *`log4j.jar`*, you will require add *`slf4j-api.jar`* and *`slf4j-log4j12.jar`*.

[image: log4jdbc configuration]

---

*Notes*

***** Images were obtained from [*JPA - Tracer les requêtes SQL avec Log4jdbc*](http://javablabla.blogspot.mx/2012/10/log4jdbc.html)